# Best way to Store Stock Symbol TimeSeries data

Tags: database-design

i am looking to store time-series data for equities, stocks symbols.
I have 4 readings. Overall, Short-Term, Intermediate-Term, Long-Term. 
I have 4000 symbols. 
I capture the data at the end of day, 6pm

what is best way to store this data in a DB

1. have 4000 tables, 1 table for each symbol. Rows are dates. Readings are columns,
2. have 4 tables 1 for each reading. Each row is a Symbol (4000 rows). Each column is a new Date (each day column increases by 1).
3. Have a New Tables for each Date, 4000 Rows for each symbol, 4 Columns for each reading

thanks for any direction with this.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is none of the above.

You don't want to restrict yourself with having multiple tables which will store similar information. I'm going to assume that the records have 3 values:

```
(Symbol, value_type, value, timestamp)
```

Where `value_type` is either `overall`, `short`, `intermediate`, `long`. With the latter three being well defined time periods for all the values.

Your table will still perform as long as you keep the right indexes, depending on the types of queries you are going to run.

I would imagine that you would want to get values based on the `symbol`, the `value_type` and a `timestamp` range. So that would be one index in that order.
If you will be retrieving all four types of values for each symbol, you would want an index on `symbol`, `timestamp`

Another way to improve the performance of the table is to partition it using a hash based function on the symbol. Check here for the MySQL version of partitioning: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-types.html

There are many optimizations that you can do to optimize retrieval time, like keeping the table sorted etc. But it all depends on the queries you are planning on asking this table.